# Are there non reduced rings who nilpotent elements has at least order 3

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Are there examples of commutative ring with identity, non reduced whose nilpotent elements has at least order $3$ i.e $ x^2=0$ implies $x=0$.

In other words $(x)\cap \mathrm{Ann} (x) = 0$

Comment: Nope. If you have an element with exponent of nilpotency $n$, then powers of that element will have lower exponent of nilpotency... you can always get it down to 2.

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily shown that if $x^2 = 0$ implies $x = 0$, then the ring has no non-trival nilpotent.

By contradiction let $x$ be a non zero nilpotent, then there exists the smallest $n$ such that $x^n = 0$. Now, $n > 2$ or $x$ would be zero, so we can consider $y = x^{n-1}$. By construction this element is non zero (otherwise violates the minimality of $n$) but $y^2 = x^{2n-2}$ with $2n - 2 > n$, so $y^2 = 0$. Contradiction!

Observe that you can repeat the same proof replacing the exponent 2 with any integer $k > 1$.

EDIT: note that $\mathrm{Ann}(x) \cap (x) = (0)$ is far from being equivalent to your first request. The following example show that even if $x$ is not nilpotent that ideal can be non trivial. Consider the ring

$$
R = \frac{K[x,y]}{yx^2}.
$$

Here the class of $x$ is not a nilpotent as $y$ does not divide $x^n$ for all $n$. Anyway the class of $yx$ lies in $\mathrm{Ann}([x]) \cap ([x])$.